# Square API: Is there any way to Direct pay to vendor account using square payment gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment, square, square-connect

We have multiple seller accounts on our website, therefore I used Square to create a vendor for a certain seller.
Square required access token for identified recipient account and we did not get any access token while creating vendor through square api.
so is there any way that can be i used pay vendor directly or transfer from client account

i gone through the Square documentation but we only able to create vendor but can't directly or transfer to vendor account.